# Find Unique Rows from given data

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to find out unique rows from the given data

In my case I am storing buy sell of the stock in stock table. So same client can buy sell same stock.

So ask is to just fetch stocks which are only BUY and not SELL by any other client.

Here is the sqlFiddle link where I have shared table structure and query I tried
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df117d/2

I am expecting result as -

```
STOCKB
STOCKD
STOCKE
```

Comment: why dont you use the EXCEPT operator ?

Comment: How?
can you modify existing query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.symbol 
FROM bulk s 
WHERE s.buy_sell='BUY' AND 'SELL' not in (
  SELECT a.buy_sell
  FROM bulk a
  WHERE a.symbol = s.symbol AND a.buy_sell='SELL'
)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6cfca/2)

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way to do it using `group by` and `having` clause, where total should equal total rows with flag *BUY* :

```
select symbol
from bulk
group by symbol
having sum(buy_sell = 'BUY') = count(*)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MBkaGeWM)

Comment: Short and sweet